# How to force Unity to update/redraw whole scene

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera

I am displaying a texture from an Android native camera and experiencing performance issues.

I recorded camera latency as follows:

```
Directly rendering with SurfaceTexture: ~80ms
In OpenGL, which introduces OES-to-FBO drawing: ~90ms
Unity rendering at 60fps (which is way faster than the camera recording fps): 100-150ms
```

It's not reasonable that Unity may have an extra latency of ~60ms.

In theory, the rendering process should be:

```
CameraHAL -> OES texture -> TextureView
CameraHAL -> OES texture -> draw to FBO (<10ms) -> GLView
CameraHAL -> OES texture -> draw to FBO (<10ms) -> Unity renders the last texture
```

For details, in my native Android plugin, I create an FBO (or 2 FBOs for double-buffering implementation) and draw from OES to FBO when onFrameAvailable() is triggered in a render thread. In the Unity Update() function, I create ExternalTexture(nativeFboTextureId) and set it to the shader.

So, the latency should only come from these processes:

```
Thread switch (from camera thread to drawingHandler thread)
OES to FBO conversion
Unity drawing frequency, which should be 16.67ms
```

Is there any internal latency in Unity? Does Unity redraw using the latest external texture?

How can I force Unity to redraw when the native frame is finished?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you're using the phone's camera and is "playing" what it sees inside Unity, right?